# Encrypting password when passing all properteis through a request object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

I have a user registration method. I'm trying to clean my code my passing properties from my request class to the create method.

**Register method**

```php
public function register(CreateUserRequest $createUser)
{
    $user = User::create($createUser->validated());

    return response()->json($user);
}
```

**CreateUserRequest class**

```php
class CreateUserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'username' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'phone_number' => 'required|unique:users,phone_number|phone:IE',
            'password' => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'phone_number.phone' => 'The phone number is invalid.',
        ];
    }
}
```

This works perfectly, except that my password is stored in plain text. How do I encrypt it using bcrypt() without having to write each property to be stored in the create method?

Comment: Why are you not using Laravel's built-in [Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication) mechanism? If this is for an actual project (and not just to play around with Laravel), I 110% recommend you use Laravel's built-in Authentication, otherwise you'll lose out on so much of Laravel's functionality, especially with regards to securing your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get the data first, update the password to be hashed then create the user.

```
public function register(CreateUserRequest $createUser) 
    {        
        $userData = $createUser->validated();
        $userData['password'] = Hash::make($userData['password']);
        $user = User::create($userData);
        return response()->json($user);
    }
```

NB: Don't forget to import Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's a really nice solution. Is there a reason for using Hash over bcrypt?

Comment: By default it uses Bcrypt, but using Hash allows you to change this in the configuration at a later date without having to go through all your code base where you're using it. However feel free to use bcrypt() if you'd prefer. If my answer has been helpful, please feel free to upvote/accept it.

Comment: Yes, you're correct - will update my answer. (Long day!)

Comment: The word encrypted for the word hashed.

Comment: Grand. Thank you!